# Year Notation Missing

Tags: support, badges

I just got awarded the copy editors badge and I noticed that Al's date notation is missing a year entry (similar to the rest):
[image]

Apparently around april 2013, dates start appear:
[image]

Is it a fiscal year, that's causing this behaviour?

Comment: It's any badge that is earned in the prior 12 months that won't have the year attached : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223324/date-that-badge-was-earned-does-not-contain-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @jonsca mentioned, we still haven't cross April of this year - hence the year won't be shown till it's past that date.

Comment: What's the reason for this? To have a date, being mentioned without year, in a new year.